# Update Query DeadLock in SQL Server when ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION and READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT are enabled

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, update, deadlock, concurrency

**Scenario:**

We had learnt that the read operations are locked by MSSQL, causing other operations to slow down.

Later, we decided to turn on two factors.

`ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION` and `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` for the entire database.

Upon enabling them, we face update query dead lock from multiple customers (having SQL Server 2008, 2012, 2014)

Blocking Transaction:-

[image]

On identifying and running the procedure to identify blocked query, we find that select query on table X has blocked the update / delete process of multiple tables.

One such blocked update statement is

```
BLOCKED UPDATE: UPDATE "ManagedComputer" SET "AGENT_EXECUTED_ON"= @P0 , "STATUS_UPDATED_TIME"= @P1 , "REMARKS"= @P2 , "MODIFIED_TIME"= @P3  WHERE ( ("ManagedComputer"."RESOURCE_ID" =  @P4 ) );

BLOCKING SELECT: SELECT "UserParams"."USER_ACCOUNT_ID", "UserParams"."PARAM_NAME", "UserParams"."PARAM_VALUE"  FROM "UserParams" WHERE  (("UserParams"."USER_ACCOUNT_ID" = 2) AND ("UserParams"."PARAM_NAME" COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS = 'stop_agent_workflow')) ;
```

Isn't the sole purpose of READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT is not to block Update/ Insert statements ?

Query that I executed to find the blocking and blocked statement is as described in the article [here](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/10/06/sql-server-quickest-way-to-identify-blocking-query-and-resolution-dirty-solution/)

Answer (score 3):

Writers block other writers of the same row regardless of isolation level. To avoid blocking during data modifications, examine execution plans to ensure only needed rows are touched by the query and perform query and index tuning as needed.

The `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` database option avoids readers from blocking writers in the default `READ COMMITTED` isolation level by using row versioning instead of locking for statement level read consistency but at the cost of additional overhead for the row version store and in-row version data. You do not need to set `ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION` to use `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT`.  `ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION` allows use of the separate `SNAPSHOT` isolation level, which provides transaction level (not just statement level) consistency using row versioning.

Comment: Thanks, for your input. reiterated my findings in the problem statement. Share your points if any.

Comment: @surendhar_s, what is the isolation level of the select query? Assuming the `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` database option is on, it will block writers only of running `REPEATABLE READ` or `SERIALIZABLE`.

Answer (score 2):

@Surendhar_s, writers still block writers in Read Committed Snapshot Isolation.

You can start investigating snapshot isolation levels by reading this great article by Brent Ozar:

[Implementing Snapshot or Read Committed Snapshot Isolation in SQL Server: A Guide](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/)

Comment: Thanks, for the data provided. reiterated my findings in the problem statement. Share your points if any.